# Turn off spellcheck for cyrillic input in Empathy

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-language, spell-checking

I have spell check enabled for the english keyboard, but when I use serbian cyrillic keyboard, I want that feature turned off, because then all the words get underlined like i spelled them wrong

How do I do this? Thanks

---

Somehow now it works just as I want in Firefox, but in Empathy it still marks all the Cyrillic words, and I just want it to mark misspelled English words

Here's an example

- Firefox (good):

[image: Firefox]

- Empathy (bad):

[image: Empathy]

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can select input language if you right click on inputbox and select from available languages (usually in sub-menu named Languages). So when you type in Serbian, right-click and select appropriate spell-checking language from context menu

Comment: I don't have that option in Empathy

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is quite old, I think it could be useful for someone.
There is setting in Empathy preferences dialog, in "Spellchecking" tab. There you can select languages for spellchecing from list of all installed ones.